# PySpark - Convert String to Timestamp via When()

Tags: pyspark

I am trying to convert a String to a Timestamp

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as psf

target_df = df \
    .withColumn(
        'my_ts',
        psf.when(
            psf.to_timestamp(psf.col("my_ts"), "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss").isNotNull(), 
            psf.to_timestamp("my_ts", "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss")
        ) \
        .psf.when(
            psf.to_timestamp(psf.col("my_ts"), "dd-MMM-yy").isNotNull(), 
            psf.to_timestamp("my_ts", "dd-MMM-yy")
        ) \
        .psf.when(
            psf.to_timestamp(psf.col("my_ts"), "yyyyMMdd").isNotNull(), 
            psf.to_timestamp("my_ts", "yyyyMMdd")
        ) \
        .otherwise(None)
    )
```

However, I get the following error:

```
IllegalArgumentException: 'when() can only be applied on a Column previously generated by when() function'
```

I have tried wrapping the `psf.col()` around the `psf.to_timestamp()` but also get an error. Any ideas how to resolve?

Comment: It's not immediately clear to me where your error is, but you could also use `df.withColumn("my_ts", psf.coalesce(psf.to_timestamp(psf.col("my_ts"), "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"), psf.to_timestamp(psf.col("my_ts"), "dd-MMM-yy"), psf.to_timestamp(psf.col("my_ts"), "yyyyMMdd"))` instead of `when`.

Comment: @pault - Thanks - that also worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were pretty much there, it's just that the `when().psf.when()` doesn't work, if you use when directly then it works.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as psf
from pyspark.sql.functions import when

df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(
    [
        ["2019-01-12"],
        ["20190112"],
        ["12/01/2019 11:22:11"],
        ["12-Jan-19"]
    ], ["my_ts"])

target_df = df \
    .withColumn(
        'my_new_ts',
        when(
            psf.to_timestamp(psf.col("my_ts"), "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss").isNotNull(), 
            psf.to_timestamp("my_ts", "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss")
        ) \
        .when(
            psf.to_timestamp(psf.col("my_ts"), "dd-MMM-yy").isNotNull(), 
            psf.to_timestamp("my_ts", "dd-MMM-yy")
        ) \
        .when(
            psf.to_timestamp(psf.col("my_ts"), "yyyyMMdd").isNotNull(), 
            psf.to_timestamp("my_ts", "yyyyMMdd")
        ) \
        .otherwise(None)
    )

df.show()
target_df.show()
```

Output:

```
+-------------------+
|              my_ts|
+-------------------+
|         2019-01-12|
|           20190112|
|12/01/2019 11:22:11|
|          12-Jan-19|
+-------------------+

+-------------------+-------------------+
|              my_ts|          my_new_ts|
+-------------------+-------------------+
|         2019-01-12|               null|
|           20190112|2019-01-12 00:00:00|
|12/01/2019 11:22:11|2019-01-12 11:22:11|
|          12-Jan-19|2019-01-12 00:00:00|
+-------------------+-------------------+
```

Also, if you want a more concise version then you can use `psf.coalesce`:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as psf

target_df = df.select("*", 
                psf.coalesce(
                    psf.to_timestamp("my_ts", "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"),
                    psf.to_timestamp("my_ts", "dd-MMM-yy"),
                    psf.to_timestamp("my_ts", "yyyyMMdd")
                ).alias("my_new_ts"))
```